# User permissions messed up after updating to 13.10

Tags: mount, permissions, shutdown, automount

Ubuntu 13.10 is not working properly since I upgraded from 13.04 - seems to be a problem with my user permissions:

1. The GUI shut down and reboot buttons do not work (no response when clicking on them) - although I can shut down the machine through the terminal or by pressing the physical power button.
2. I cannot mount my external USB HD drive - it appears under 'my devices' but when I click on it, I get 'unable to access "SAMSUNG" not authorized to perform operation".
3. Same as (2) for when I try to play a DVD - I am not authorized to access the CDROM.
4. If I try to log into a guest session I get a lot of 'Ubuntu has experienced an internal error' messages.
5. In 'user accounts' I cannot click the unlocked padlock in order to make changes - when hovering above it shows 'system policy prevents changes. contact your system administrator' - even though my account shows I am the administrator.

PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything to resolve the problem? If problems persist, a good option would be to **return to 13.10** by *reinstalling* (?) as long as you can ___back up your files.___

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I haven't tried anything to fix it yet as I have no ideas! How would I re-install without losing my setting/software installations etc?